# Meaning of "c" notation at end of St Louis obituaries?

Tags: united-states, 1920s, missouri, newspaper, obituary

The image below is an portion of obituaries from [this full page](https://www.newspapers.com/clip/6042642//) (page 21 of the St. Louis Post-Dispatch on 5 Feb 1923).  Right aligned on the last line of most obituaries is one of the following:

- (c)
- (c1)
- (c2)
- (c48)

What do these mean?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those numbers appear to have nothing to do with the obituary information.

If you look at the rest of the full page you linked to, you'll see (2) and (c2) and (c8) and (c14) and other such codes in the same location after many of the want ads that are to the right of the obituaries you show in the image.

[image]

It must be some sort of code used by the newspaper, maybe for example to identify who added the entry.